# Can't fetch JSON In Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have the follow Backbone.js code

```
var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,
    url: '/api/items',
});
```

and then in my view I'm trying to do the following to fetch the JSON from the API and populate the models

```
this.collection = new List();

var that = this;
this.collection.fetch({
    success: function () {
        that.render();
        console.log('Fetch successful!');
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Failed to fetch!');
    }
});
```

However the fetch is not working and its triggering the "Failed to fetch!" message.  Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong?  If I go to the `api/items` in my browser I get prompted to download the JSON file so its definitely there and when I open it up its new line delimited.  Below is a snippet of the api code that sends back the JSON

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-json-stream'
});

setTimeout(function () {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<limit; i+=1) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(createRandomItem(i+skip, sort)) + '\n');
    }
    res.end();
}, 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000));
```

Also when I use developer tools to check the request that was sent to the API the response I get back just seems to be random characters and I get the error **"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: Unexpected character"**

```
eyJpZCI6IjAtd202MzNjYTF0Y3ZqOWs5Iiwic2l6ZSI6MTYsInByaWNlIjo5MzgsImZhY2
```

Comment: Try just `res.send(200, {your array/objects/etc})`

Comment: I'm not sure but can it be so that streaming JSON content type is not supported by your browser JS implementation? AFAIK, Backbone uses simple `XMLHttpRequest` object to deal with requesting collections. What if you use simple `application/json` type?

Comment: I've tried changing the content type to `application/json` but I got the same result.  Also I should point out that if possible I don't want to change the server side code.

Comment: @Bender How does your backend generate the response? Does it close the connection? Can it be possible that the request is timed out?

Comment: @VisioN I've updated my question with more code to show this

Comment: Why do you expect any JSON parser to be able to parse invalid JSON? if your content-type is `'application/x-json-stream'` the server should generate a valid JSON string

Comment: Did you try to validate the json data, if no try http://jsonlint.com/ or any other service. Add  'parse'  function in collection definition and try to print the data there also ,
Eg:- " parse: function (resp, xhr) {
console.log(resp);         
  return resp;
       }"

Comment: @Bender, was your issue solved?

Answer (score 9):

Your response writing loop generate invalid json string, because it just concatenate json objects.

You can gather all objects in array and stringify it like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var i, data = [];
    for (i=0; i<limit; i+=1) {
        data.push(createRandomItem(i+skip, sort));
    }

    res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    res.end();
}, 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000));
```

Comment: Thanks this works if I also changed the content type to `application/json` but is there anyway I can get it to work without changing the back end code?

Comment: You want the native `JSON.parse` to be able to parse invalid JSON? I believe that is not possible.

Comment: @Bender, you would need customize `Backbone.sync` to read server response as plain text, split response by some delimiter (\n in your case), `JSON.parse` one by one and then gather them client side. I think its much better to just output valid JSON on server side.

Comment: @Bender this answer is correct. The issue is that your server is generating invalid json data and therefore an invalid response. Its not valid JSON so your application cannot read it as such. The issue lies in your server side code and needs to be resolved there

Answer (score 4):

Typically, when you get a **JSON.parse: unexpected character** error, it indicates that the JSON attributes are not double-quote-qualified, so basically the JSON might look like this:

```
"{ test: 1, testing: 2 }"          *Invalid*
```

Or even this:

```
"{ 'test': 1, 'testing': 2 }"      *Invalid*
```

Instead of like this:

```
'{ "test": 1, "testing": 2 }'      *Valid*
```

Or this:

```
"{ \"test\": 1, \"testing\": 2 }"  *Valid*
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing's first.  You definitely have server configuration issues.  It sounds like your mime type is not set and you have (possibly gzip) compression enabled.

Use Google Chrome to browse to the URL that serves up the JSON.  The browser should display the JSON in plain text without prompting you to download it.

Next get the JSONView extension for Chrome. Browse to the URL that serves up the JSON.  You should see the JSON in "pretty" format with matching braces.

After you have that, go back to your web app and test.  If you are still having problems, post your web server information (type and version) and any other special info.  We'll go from there.